# How to use createImageBitMap to get ImageData from a dropped File?

Tags: javascript, canvas, ecmascript-6, fetch, web-worker

So, with the new createImageBitmap in Chrome and Firefox, [we now have a way to turn image Blobs into ImageData](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/03/createimagebitmap-in-chrome-50), suitable for manipulation in canvas. This even works in a webworker, meaning we can move Image decoding and preloading off the main thread.  However, while it works great for fetched images, I'm struggling to figure out a sane way to make it work with a user droppped file. In theory, since createImageBitmap accepts a Blob as its argument ([among other things, like ImageData, or another ImageBitmap object.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageBitmapFactories/createImageBitmap)), it should accept a File (since File is a subtype of Blob). In practice, however, I just get a blank/black image back.  Oddly, I can get all this to work if I convert the file into a dataURL and then "fetch" it. Here's the webworker code for that:

```
self.addEventListener('message', function(e) {
  var file = e.data;

  var reader = new FileReader();

  reader.onload = function(){ 
    fetch(reader.result)
      .then(response => response.blob())
      .then(blob => createImageBitmap(blob))
      .then(imageData=>{
        self.postMessage(imageData,[imageData]);
      }).catch( _ => {
        !console.log('worker error!', _);
        self.postMessage({error:'error'});
      });
  };

  reader.readAsDataURL(file);

}, false);
```

That works, but it seems incredibly convoluted, especially the extra step of reading out the File image into a dataURL needlessly.  I feel like I must be missing some obvious way to convert a File into a Blob (but can't find any api for it, again since in theory a File IS already a Blob!) or use readAsArrayBuffer and then some other transformation to get it into a type that createImageBitmap can use (the end goal, again, being getting to the ImageData type).

Comment: This works for me with a file: https://jsfiddle.net/ngarsk3d/ - Can you show the code you're using that *doesn't* work?

Comment: Hunh. Could it be that it's just a bug in the webworker side of things?

Comment: Here's one which uses a WebWorker to do the conversion - https://plnkr.co/edit/of3S0B76f1m0WP6bTFUT?p=preview - seems to work fine

Comment: @CodingIntrigue works for me in Chrome but not in Firefox.  Has it ever worked in FF for you?

Comment: filed as a bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1439217